# Creating new file in Aptana 3 without creating a new project

Tags: ide, aptana, aptana3, new-project

How would I be able to create a new .php or .html (examples) in Aptana 3 without going to the process of creating a new project file in order to accomplish it.

I am running on a Mac and running Aptana Studio 3.2.2

If someone could lead me to the right direction with a link to how, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every file need to be part of a project.

I use to keep a spare project where I can quickly open temporary working files without the need to create a new project.

Comment: How can you create a new .php file to a project?

Comment: In the **Project Explorer** just right click on the project name and choose **New** and **File**. A popup window will appear where you can enter a **File Name** and press **Finish** to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

File>New From template>HTML>Choose the type of HTML file you would like to create and you are set